# How to Send and Retrieve Map collection data to next Activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some data in Map collection.I want to send and retrieve it in next activity

exa.

```
        Map data=new HashMap();
        data.put("name","abc");
        data.put("status","Busy in work");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmsVerActivity.class);

        //pass Map collection data to next activity
        intent.putExtra("vercode",data.get("vercode").toString());
        intent.putExtra("cname",data.get("cname").toString());
        intent.putExtra("status_txt",data.get("status_txt").toString());

         startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any shortcut way to do this ??

I mean can we pass Like below ??

```
intent.putExtra("data",data);
```

So that i can retrieve it in SmsVerActivity as

```
Bundle extras=getintent().getExtras();
//get data from MainActivity        
String name=extras.getCharSequence(data.get("name"));
String status=extras.getCharSequence(data.get("status_txt"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `HashMap` implementation you can use

```
bundle.putExtra("map", (Serializable) map);
```

because `HashMap` implements `Serializable` interface.

How to retrieve it in another `Activity`?

```
 map = (Map) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("map");
```

Comment: But how to retrieve this in my another activity ??

Comment: This is dog slow if the map is large.

Comment: @DavidWasser It seems to be not in this case, he have only a few keys with Strings.

Comment: if i have much more data then what should i use ??

Comment: @pathe.kiran then you should implements `Parcelable`

Comment: @pathe.kiran add upvote also, I enjoy that ;)

Comment: Need 15 reputation to upvote. So sorry for that.